# can't see global variable after 'extract'

Tags: php

In my **main.php** file, I prepare an array of values. 
I 'extract' that array, before 'include' another file(**template.php**).
all the keys of the array are available inside template.php as varaibles(thx to 'extract' function),
But when using them in functions defined in **template.php** the variables are not visible to scope, and instead i get 'uninitialize value' error.

I thought its because of variable scope, but 'global' keyword didn't solve the problem.

Here is short version of code.

```
// main.php

$array = ["page" => "my current page"];

extract($array);
include('template.php');

// template.php
<?php

    function foo(){
        // global $page; // putting 'global' didn't make it work
        print $page;    // uninitialized variable; 

    }

    print $page;        // work OK - print $page value
    foo();

?>
```

Thx

Comment: Why do you use extract()? Why can't you just use the array?

Comment: They'll certainly become local variables in your *template* script, not global ones. Declaring something outside of functions does not imply the global scope by itself.

Comment: If you must use global variables like that, the `global` keyword like you used it, is the way to do it. And it works too: http://codepad.viper-7.com/QcXDuk.

Comment: Don't use `extract`. Littering your namespace is bad practice, plus you'd have to globalize EVERY variable you create like that in every function you want to use them. Just keep them all as entries in `$array`, then you only have to do `global $array`, and not `global $foo, $bar, $baz, blah blah blahblah, $whatever`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of attempting to use global variables (which isn't a great idea) you could simply modify the `foo()` method to accept a variable.

**Main.php**

```
<?php

$array = array("page" => "my current page");

extract($array);
include('template.php');
?>
```

**Template.php**

```
<?php

    function foo($page)
    {
        print 'The page is: ' . $page;
    }

    foo($page);

?>
```

Extracted variables won't be accessible in your functions, but they can be sent in as regular parameters. (This is provided that you are in the proper scope to use them.)

[See it in action](http://codepad.org/snEHoHl2)

Comment: Extracted variables work the same as any other variable.

Comment: This is true, but OP's problem is that he can't access the extracted `$page` in his function because the scope is incorrect.  So his options are to go with globals or use a parameter to pass the extracted `$page` into his function where it will be used.

Comment: The question doesn't really add up, using the `global` keywork would have worked for a global - extracted - variable. So I might have mis-interpreted your last paragraph with that in mind. Anyway, yours is the way to do it...

Comment: Yeah I agree, the `global $page;` in his function should have did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
// main.php
$array = ["page" => "my current page"];

createVars($array);

function createVars($data) {
    foreach($data as $key => $val) {
        global ${$key};
        ${$key} = $val;
    }
}

include ('template.php');


// template.php
function foo(){
    global $page;
    print $page;
}
foo();
// you should now be able to access $page inside of foo();
```